# How to watch pending state for useAsyncData in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to run code after I'm finished fetching data from the server, like this:

```js
const { data: initialState, pending } = await useAsyncData('budgetInitialState', async () => {
    const initialState = await getInitialState()
    return initialState
})

watch(() => pending, (newPending) => {
    if (!newPending) { // This means the pending is now false, and data fetching is done.
        onMounted(async () => {
            console.log('never getting here')
        })
    }
})
```

but the code in the `onMounted` hook is never being accessed.

Comment: Think you cannot place the onMounted inside the watch function. The other way round might work.